# Could not clone remote repository

Tags: git, hudson, redhat

I have Hudson running in Red Hat Enterprise 5. In Hudson, I use Git to clone remote repository. I get this error when cloning code:

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' 
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone <repo url>
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:241)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:919)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:919)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:698)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1515)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:521)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:428)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: <repo   url>: not authorized
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:234)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:221)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:221)
    ... 13 more
```

I see "not authorized" in the trace above, so I guess this may because I haven't setup Git account (username/password). I searched every config in Hudson's configure and job's configure but I couldn't find where to specify the password. Please help me!

Comment: `<repo   url>` the url seems empty. Is it normal or did you removed it from the output in this question, for confidentiality reason?

Comment: yes, I removed it for confidentiality

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Hudson runs as a separate user, so while Hudson tries to clone something, it will search for a private key to authenticate.

You should,

Switch as root

```
$sudo -i
```

Then switch as hudson user

```
$su hudson
```

Generate ssh-key

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'email_id_for_authentication'
```

Copy the public key from .ssh folder in ~hudson (hudson user's home folder)

Add it to your remote repository.

Set user.email for git in user hudosn

```
$git config --global user.email "email_id_for_authentication"
```

You can do the same under git-plugin config in `Manage Hudson > Configure System`

Comment: the matter is I can't put anything to the remote repository. Is there another way like in Windows I just put username/password in a _netrc file and I can clone any remote code.

Comment: its a two way authentication, remote needs to know the ssh client connecting is an authenticated one, so it needs your public key. B/w are you talking about public github repos? if so use https instead of git/ssh protocol as repo url.

Comment: It's private github repos requiring username/password